# Check if Python Requests response is http or https

Tags: python-requests, httprequest

I am currently using this clumsy way to check if a request is HTTP or HTTPS

```
def get_scheme(self, request):
    if self.request.url.startswith('https:'):
            scheme = 'https'
        else:
            scheme = 'http'
```

Is there a `request.is_secure()` method in Python Requests?